# MooTools Page Peel back image sticking out on effect

Tags: mootools

I have a Mootools Page Peel function that works well, except that when you hover over the 'small' image(small peel), and the bigger one expands, the back image can be seen behind the front image suppose to cover it. Please see my example: http://jsfiddle.net/uc6PJ/1/ 
I made the animation slow so that you can see what I mean - Look at the bottom part of the effect, you will see it does not look right.

Thank You!

Comment: er. http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/3DHoverEffects/ - look at all 4 demos. the word has moved on, CSS3 offers you far greater stuff than 'peeling'.

Comment: I see there is JQuery involved. Nonetheless, very impressive, love it. Thanks

Comment: the js is just support - you can easily refactor that to mootools :)

Comment: Thanks mate, appreciate. You look like you know a lot more about Javascript than I do, could you pleas just take a look at my code and see why th back image sticks out on the mouseenter event. it is really simple code

Comment: i had a look and i even nearly fixed it but the problem is that the images are not of the same size/scale exactly and then the shadow keeps going. also, when you do 2 separate morphs, this causes 2 separate setTimeout forks to work on a different timer - even if started at the same time. it won't be smooth - instead, you can use Fx.Elements from mootools more, which can animate multiple ones on the same timer. then all you need to do is work around the differences in images and positioning and it will be silky smooth.